# How to add control the cache of a restful service operation by operation?

Tags: wcf, rest, caching

I've written a rest service using WCF. The service contains several operations. Some are GET based (`[WebGet]`), others are POST based (`[WebInvoke]`).

The service is working as expected. However, the GET based operations are put in the client cache, which is not desirable for all operations.

After a bit a search, I've found [How to prevent the browser from caching WCF JSON responses](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2009/09/07/how-to-prevent-the-browser-from-caching-wcf-json-responses.aspx). This is working, but I found it's not very reusable.

My platform does not allows me to update the web.config. Actually, my service is part of a SharePoint project. and updating the web.config file is hard to implement properly. This forbid me to use the `[WebCache]` attribute.

So I implemented a custom `MessageInspector` which fix the proper headers:

```
public class CacheAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase host)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CacheInspector(m_CacheEnabled, CacheDuration));
            }
        }
    }
     /*...
        Other code omitted for brievty
     */

}

public class CacheInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
     /*...
        Code omitted for brievety
     */

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;

        if (m_CacheEnabled)
        {
            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow + CacheDuration.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            cache.SetNoStore();
        }

    }
}
```

This code is working as expected, but it applies to all operations in the service.

**How can I code an attribute based class that apply the same logic, but at the operation scope** ?

I've tried to find something useful in the `IOperationBehavior` interface, but I did not find the appropriate implementation.

Full code (.net 4.5):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CacheAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{

    private readonly bool m_CacheEnabled;

    public bool CacheEnabled  { get { return m_CacheEnabled; } }

    public TimeSpan? CacheDuration { get; set; } 

    public CacheAttribute(bool cacheEnabled)
    {
        this.m_CacheEnabled = cacheEnabled;
    }
    public CacheAttribute(TimeSpan cacheDuration) : this(true)
    {
        this.CacheDuration = cacheDuration;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase host)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CacheInspector(m_CacheEnabled, CacheDuration));
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }



    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

}

public class CacheInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    private readonly bool m_CacheEnabled;
    private readonly TimeSpan? CacheDuration;

    public CacheInspector(bool m_CacheEnabled, TimeSpan? CacheDuration)
    {
        this.m_CacheEnabled = m_CacheEnabled;
        this.CacheDuration = CacheDuration;
    }
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;

        if (m_CacheEnabled)
        {
            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow + CacheDuration.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            cache.SetNoStore();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what your are looking for.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CacheAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IParameterInspector
{
    public TimeSpan CacheLifetime { get; private set; }

    public CacheAttribute(double lifetime)
    {
        this.CacheLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lifetime);
    }

    #region IOperationBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {}

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation) {}

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription) {}

    #endregion

    #region IParameterInspector Members

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        if (this.CacheLifetime == TimeSpan.Zero) {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        } else {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", string.Format("max-age={0}",this.CacheLifetime.TotalSeconds));
        }
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

usage

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICacheTestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CurrentTime")]
    [Cache(0)]
    string GetCurrentTime();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CurrentTimeCached")]
    [Cache(30)]
    string GetCurrentTimeCached();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CurrentTimeNoCC")]
    string GetCurrentTimeNoCC();
}
```